# How to force ActualWidth and ActualHeight to update (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, actualwidth, actualheight

I a grid on my silverlight control, I am programatically adding a canvas, and in the canvas I am loading and displaying Image.

I'm also adding a rotation to the canvas.  The problem is that by default the CenterX and CenterY of the rotation is the top left of the canvas.  What I want is the rotation to happen around the centre of the canvas.

To do this, I've tried setting the CenterX and CenterY of the Rotation to the Images `ActualWidth` / 2 and `ActualHeight` / 2, however I've discovered that `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are not always populated, at least not right away. How can I force them to get updated?

Even using the DownloadProgress event on the image doesn't seem to guarantee the ActualWidth and ActualHeight are populated, and neither does using this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()...

```
Image imgTest = new Image();
Canvas cnvTest = new Canvas();
Uri uriImage = new Uri("myurl", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmpDisplay = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uriImage);

bmpDisplay.DownloadProgress += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.DownloadProgressEventArgs>(this.GetActualDimensionsAfterDownload);

imgTest.Source = bmpDisplay;
imgTest.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
imgTest.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
imgTest.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

cnvTest.Children.Add(imgTest);

this.grdLayout.Children.Add(imgTest);
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(GetActualDimensions));
```

Answer (score 15):

To update the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of a `FrameworkElement` you will have to call `UpdateLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, calling updateLayout doesn't always work either depending on your situation.

I've had better luck doing something like:

```
whateverUIElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()
  {
   //code that needs width/height here
  }
);
```

but even that fails too often.

Answer (score 1):

Most reliable method I found is to use **DependencyPropertyDescriptor** **AddValueChanged** listeners of **ActualWidth** and **ActualHeight** instead of **OnLayoutUpdated** to get element sizes after rendering

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ActualWidthProperty, typeof(StackPanel));
if (descriptor != null)
{
    descriptor.AddValueChanged(uiPanelRoot, DrawPipelines_LayoutUpdated);
}

descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ActualHeightProperty, typeof(StackPanel));
if (descriptor != null)
{
    descriptor.AddValueChanged(uiPanelRoot, DrawPipelines_LayoutUpdated);
}


void DrawPipelines_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Point point1 = elementInstrumentSampleVial.TranslatePoint(
    //                new Point(11.0, 15.0), uiGridMainInner);
}
```

Instead of using StackPanel, Grid etc. use base element that you are depending on for relative sizes

Comment: `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: You could try listen LayoutUpdated or create some delay using DispatcherTimer, but it probably would not guarantee results